# MySql - executing JOIN with condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have 2. tables: videos and videos_lang. I join these tables with LEFT JOIN when I want to get information about a video in selected language. And here is the problem: if the translation in selected language doesn't exist, I want to join translation in default language (which always exists). How can I do that?
I use that sql query:

```
SELECT vl.\*, v.* 
FROM videos v 
LEFT JOIN videos_lang vl 
ON vl.sig = 'de' AND v.idVideo = vl.idVideo
```

How to get translation where vl.sig = 'en' (en is the defualt language)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(vl.idVideo, vl_en.idVideo),
  v.*
FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM videos_lang WHERE sig = 'de') vl
  ON v.idVideo = vl.idVideo
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM videos_lang WHERE sig = 'en') vl_en
  ON v.idVideo = vl_en.idVideo
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. How to get whole information about selected translation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using OR condition inside your join query like this

```
SELECT vl.*, v.* FROM videos v LEFT JOIN videos_lang vl 
ON (vl.sig = 'de' OR vl.sig = 'en') AND v.idVideo = vl.idVideo
```

Comment: But it doesn't work properly when I am using LIMIT (to many records - if there are two translations for one item e.g. in 'de' and 'en' and I want to get only two items I get one item with two translations).